# Can I use maphilight plug in to highlight areas with same class on two different maps?

Tags: jquery, css, highlight, imagemap, maphilight

If I have two different maps (for different images) displayed side by side, can I use `maphilight` to highlight area from each map with the same class?

I'm looking for something similar to how `groupBy` works on one map.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the query (pun intended).

Use a `name` tag to link  the areas together (if you've multiple areas in one image grouped using `groupBy`, then use the name tag on only one of those areas. Else, it'll cause multiple hover effect and lead to darkening of the highlight due to overlapping).

Then in jQuery, use
`$('area[name="foo"]').mouseover();`